# how to disable the past date in date picker in android studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How to disable the post date in the date picker in android and when we select the start date randomly. And we will get the end date to equal to the start date or next date

Answer (score 0):

try with minDate in date picker `datePicker.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000`
and if you are using calender than use

```
 calender.datePicker.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

easy code

**Call**

```
setDate(textview, this, true)
```

**Method**

```
     fun setDate(txtView: TextView, context: Context, show_future_dates: Boolean) {
        var date: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
        var thisAYear = date.get(Calendar.YEAR).toInt()
        var thisAMonth = date.get(Calendar.MONTH).toInt()
        var thisADay = date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).toInt()

        val dpd = DatePickerDialog(
            context,
            R.style.DialogTheme,
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener { view2, thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay ->
                thisAMonth = thisMonth + 1
                thisADay = thisDay
                thisAYear = thisYear

                txtView.text = thisADay.toString() + "/" + thisAMonth + "/" + thisAYear
                val newDate: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
                newDate.set(thisYear, thisMonth, thisDay)
            },
            thisAYear,
            thisAMonth,
            thisADay
        )
        dpd.datePicker.spinnersShown = true
        dpd.datePicker.calendarViewShown = false
        if (show_future_dates) {
            dpd.datePicker.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000
        } else if (!show_future_dates) {
            dpd.datePicker.maxDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
        }
        dpd.show()
    }
```